# Javascript: Cannot read property 'style' of null on Else at divToHide

Tags: javascript

As the title says, the error is "cannot read property 'style' of `null`.

```
<body class="container">
  <div class="row img">
    <div class="col-lg-2"><img onclick="divToHide(q1);" class="poster" src="img/batman-begins.jpg">
      <div style="display: none;" id="q1">Batman Begins (2005)
        <br> FSK: 12 Action, Adventure 16.06.2005
        <br>After training with his mentor, Batman begins his fight to free crime-ridden Gotham City from the corruption that Scarecrow and the League of Shadows have cast upon it.
        <br> Director: Christopher Nolan</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2"><img onclick="divToHide(q2);" class="poster" src="img/x-men.jpg">
      <div style="display: none;" id="q2">X-Men (2000)
        <br> FSK: 12 Action, Adventure, Sci-Fi 31.08.2000
        <br>Two mutants come to a private academy for their kind whose resident superhero team must oppose a terrorist organization with similar powers.
        <br> Director: Bryan Singer</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 last-Child" style="display: none;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row menu">
    <div class="col-lg-2 last-Child1" style="display: none;"></div>
  </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function divToHide(id) {
    var div = document.getElementById(id);
    if (div.style.display == 'block') {
      div.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      div.style.display = 'block';
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the onclick="divToHide(q1);" to onclick="divToHide('q1');" and so on.